# Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker.QnAMakerDialog How to override not found?

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I'm working with `QnAMakerDialog` and cannot figure out how to override the "not found". I am able to override `RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync` but that is not called when no answer is found. I tried setting the default message to null or empty string but then `QnAMakerDialog` automatically response "No match found!" when it doesn't find a match!

I don't want a message when no match is found because I'm just forwarding the message to a `LuisDialog`. How do I stop this message!!!

Side note: I understand that some Gary guy has a different version of a `QnAMakerDialog` that does this but I'd really like to just use the standard one from Microsoft. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That "Gary guy" is Gary Pretty. He made a nice job on `QnAMaker`, especially a few days ago by providing access to QnAMaker API v3 through a package, which provides a lot of new features compared to `QnAMakerDialog`.

For every user coming to your question and looking for a similar answer, you should definitely have a look to his package:

- It's open source ! So on [GitHub](https://github.com/garypretty/botframework/tree/master/QnAMakerDialog)
- On Nuget [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QnAMakerDialog/)

With his package, you can directly override `NoMatchHandler` and you're done.

---

For those who are reluctant to use a third-party package, even if you have the code, the "official" `QnAMakerDialog` comes from `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices` package, which sources are... also on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices).

So if you look in `QnAMakerDialog.cs` you will see that everything you need is inside `MessageReceivedAsync` method, in particular the message is sent by this [line](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Library/QnAMaker/QnAMaker/QnAMakerDialog.cs#L121):

```
await context.PostAsync(qnaMakerResults.ServiceCfg.DefaultMessage);
```

As you can also see:

- `MessageReceivedAsync` can't be overridden easily
- even if you hide this method with `new` and copy paste all the method except the line, you will have problems with some properties like `serviceCfg` that are internal so can't be used in your own namespace

So the last option will be to copy all the QnA classes from Microsoft Github's project just to remove this line...

---

EDIT:

As you can see on https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices, there are several issues pending around this problem:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/issues/50
- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/issues/58
- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/issues/75

I hope there will be an integration in the package soon, as several Pull Request have been provided around that

Comment: Yes, after overriding every virtual method in the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMakerDialog I came to the same conclusion as you. It just isn't setup for what I want to do.

I installed Gary's code and it works great. It's not that I am against 3rd party code, or open source, I just like to know for sure if I am downloading stuff unnecessarily that I can actually do, easily, without. Thank you, and much thanks to Gary Pretty.